# Ignite put vs DataStreaming

Tags: java, ignite

I have large amount of `IgniteRunnable` that Im going to execute with `IgniteCompute`. They look as follows:

```
public class MyIgniteRunnable implements IgniteRunnable{

    private Sting value;
    private String key;

    public MyIgniteRunnable(String key, String value){
         this.key = key;
         this.value = value;
    }

    public void run{

        IgniteCache<String, String> cache = Ignition.localIgnite().getOrCreateCache("cache");
        String previous = cache.get(key);
        String result;
        //process previous and value
        cache.put(key, result); //<------ Here

    }

}
```

Im going to use it as follows:

```
Ignite ignite;
String key;
String value;
//...
IgniteCompute compute = ignite.compute();
compute.affinityRun("cache", key, new MyIgniteRunnable(key, value));
```

But Im not sure if using `put` in the task is the right thing to do. I thought that since I use `affinityRun` with the `key` each task will be executed on the "right" node, so `put` is okay, cos no additiobal serialization/networking cost.

Is this approach correct or there is some more efficient way to do this?

I didnt use streaming because there is only one element in each task to put into cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to execute some logic based on the cached value, then your approach is correct and probably the simplest. The best way to execute your logic is on the node that stores the key. Because you are using affinityRun(...) the cache put operation will be local and there will be no redundant network traffic.

On the other hand, you could also use the DataStreamer as well, which should render better performance, but is a bit more complex for the cases when you have to execute some collocated logic on the server side. Take a look at the StreamReciever, StreamTransformer, and StreamVisitor documented here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-streamers

Comment: I was not sure about performance of dataStreamers in that case. I know about stream transformers. In order to execute some logic I need to get cache element. So I wanted to send the task across the network only once to the right node and then get, process, and put (all operations are local).

Comment: Or stream receiver is already executed on the right node, so no additional network traffic and serialization cost?